# HTML5 Geolocation only move marker

Tags: html, geolocation

Hi I am using the code here http://rominirani.com/html5-recipes-more-on-geolocation/ to implement a user tracking app built in HTML5.

The issue I have is that whenever I move, the map completely re-renders. Is there a way to just update the marker position and set the center of the map to that position or is there a better way to implement Google maps with a marker that moves when the user moves?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the HTML5 geolocation API with Google Maps to add/remove a marker on a position change listener

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition
```

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-remove